# How to Find Ticks for Research

Tags: research-process, research-tools

I am an amateur researcher looking for castor bean ticks for a science project. Where could I procure them the easiest? I am located in southern California.

Comment: Why castor bean ticks specifically? There are lots of USA native species that might work in their place rather than getting one largely found in Europe.

Comment: We want Ixodes ricinus specifically because we are experimenting with their reaction to static electric fields and that interaction has only been shown with Ixodes ricinus so far.

Comment: Where do you live? How you obtain them most easily vs. most economically depends in part on where you live.

Comment: Near Los Angeles.

Comment: I'll assume (danger!) that your Ixodes behaves like most Ixodes do. The way "questing" ticks (e.g. Ixodes scapularis) are collected is to go where they are common and use a white flannel cloth attached to a pole, the ends of which are tied to a rope, then dragged behind oneself and checked periodically for ticks and collected if present. This works wonderfully for a variety of applications. If that mostly European tick isn't common near to where you live, then you'll have to buy them. Sorry I don't have a better suggestion.

Comment: I should add that the cloth should be weighted. Here's a [link](https://www.publichealthontario.ca/-/media/documents/S/2015/sop-active-tick-dragging.pdf?la=en) in case of interest. You might try exposing Ixodes scapularis to a static electric field; they aren't very different ticks, and are probably abundant somewhere not too distant from your location. Where I live (a hotspot for Lyme), I could probably find a hundred in a couple of hours or less this time of year.